# Segfault with List insert?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I feel like I might be overlooking something very extremely simple here, but I have made some code just to test out insert / splice on lists and I am getting a seg-fault on the code I made.  Can someone tell me where / why?

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
int main(){

vector <int> iVec;
list <int> iList;
vector<int>::iterator vIt;
list <int>::iterator lIt;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    iVec.push_back(i*10);
    iList.push_back(i*10);
}//0, 10, 20, 30....90


//0 <-- current pos of iterator lIt

lIt++;  
lIt++; 

//0, 10, 20

iList.insert(lIt, 3);



//Vector output loop
for(vIt = iVec.begin(); vIt!= iVec.end(); vIt++){

}



cout << endl << endl <<"List Contents: " <<endl << endl;
//List output loop
for(lIt = iList.begin(); lIt != iList.end(); lIt++){
    cout << *lIt << endl;
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: You haven't initialised your iterators. `list <int>::iterator lIt = iList.begin()`

Comment: @spraff, if you posted that as an answer, we can vote!

Comment: Have you tried running your code through a debugger? What did you see?

Comment: Why didn't you indent your code? Did you use a debugger? Valgrind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lIt` has not been correctly initialized - it is an iterator - but currently does not point to anything - you need to do this:

```
lIt = iList.begin(); // initialize it to begin, now we can iterate!
```

Comment: Oh man, I'm an idiot!! Up until now I've been using iterators within for loops for output purposes, so I didn't even think that I didn't initialize it!! Thanks!

Comment: Declaring variables at the top of a function is an archaic C idiom --  best practice for C++ is to create variables only where needed, in the narrowest possible scope, always initialised, and const if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
lIt++;  
lIt++;
```

You've not intialized `lIt` iterator, yet you're incrementing it. That is the problem.

Initialize it then increment:

```
lIt = iList.begin();
lIt++;  
lIt++;
```

Answer (score 1):

The comments always lie!

```
//0 <-- current pos of iterator lIt
```

No it's not. `lIt` is not initialised at this point.

Comment: eh? I'm going mad, I'm sure when I read the original it said "is initialised".. :) ignore me..